# Brownian motion hitting probability of boundary and going outside

Tags: probability, reference-request, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I was solving an exercise which asks the reader to calculate the probability that a Brownian particle $B(t) = (B_1(t),...,B_n(t))$ starting at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^n$ will strike the surface of a cube $B = [-1, 1]^n$ within time $t$. I understand how to do this, because each coordinate $B_i(t)$ is an independent Brownian motion whose distribution is known. But I am wondering about the following: is this probability the same as being **outside** of the cube within time $t$? In other words, is 
$$\mathbb{P}_0(B(s) \in \partial B : \text{ for some } s \leq t) = \mathbb{P}_0(B(s) \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \overline{B} : \text{ for some } s \leq t)?$$

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well i have no proof or anything and i may be wrong but it seems to me that the two probabilities are different because your bm can start at the origin, hit the boundary of the cube and stay a little bit on the boundary before leaving the cube or going back inside.

Comment: @anonymus I don't know for sure, but my first introduction to Brownian motion came from Kinetic theory of gases. The intuition is, the Brownian particle is supposed to "vibrate" incessantly. If that is the case, "staying a little bit on the boundary" could have probability $0$. Of course, this is a heuristic only.